# css not being applied to div when giving class name

Tags: html, css

i have a listing html page, in which the first div background color will be white and the second grey color. i have used the following css

```css
.aamir {
  background: #fff;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  height: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fafafa
}
```

the problem is when i am using the class name like

> .aamir:nth-child(even)

its not working. when i am using

> div:nth-child(even)

its working fine. can anyone please tell me why i cannot give it my class. thanks in advance.

Comment: It should work fine, maybe because you didn't add ``.`` dot before the class name ``.aamir:nth-child(even)``

Comment: Can you also show us the relevant HTML?

Comment: @Light i got it from the answer section. specificity problem

Comment: Please can this question be reopened?  As seen below the question has been answered so it was clear enough and doesn't need to be closed.

Comment: i dont understand why this question is off topic, then what questions should be asked here. about movies?

Comment: read the full banner and when it says : *to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.* .. You have not HTML code provided so no one can give you a clear answer and the accepted answer was a *guess* that was correct. We don't want guesses but we want clear question and precise answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, i think your CSS selector is incorrect.  You would need to do the following (note, the starting period):

```css
.aamir:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fafafa
}
```

Second, i think you might be suffering because of the specificity.  You can try the below CSS to get around it. This will make it more specific than the original selector by using the element type as well as the class.  If your element type is not a div, change the CSS to match the element type.

```css
div.aamir:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fafafa
}
```

You can find out more about specificity at: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

Comment: thanks ,specifity was my problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to forget to add a dot before `aamir`.

```css
.aamir:nth-child(even) {
    background: #fafafa;
}
```

Comment: . is not my problem, i forgot to add it in my question. i have updated the question

Comment: Then could you add the html to your post as well. Would help to identify the issue better.